# The inner mechanism of WP SEO plugins

Tags: seo

This is more of a conceptual question, but it has actual ramifications.

Going through the various SEO plugins I found nowhere a PHP tag that should be embedded in the actual HTML page and echo the meta data. How does it work then?

Simply saving it to the DB doesn't seem enough. What is the mechanism through which the plugin "injects" the SEO data to the page?

Comment: Wiki style: *{CITATION NEEDED}*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are talking about adding meta tags and changing the title they rely on `wp_head` action being fired at theme header before the `</head>`tag is generated.

For changing the title they probably use the `wp_title` filter.
Older versions of "all in one seo" used to buffer the head section and replace the title tag in something like

```
add_action('init','start_buf');
function start_buf( {
  ob_start();
}

add_action('wp_head','end_buf');
function end_buf() {
  $head = ob_get_contents();
  $head = string replace '<title>....</title>' in $head with the configured title
  ob_end_clean();
  echo $head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SEO plugins inject their code like meta tags or schema JSON-LD via WordPress hooks like `wp_head` or `wp_footer`. It's important for themes to implement these hooks (which is a requirement for theme development). Otherwise, a lot of functionality in WP will break, including SEO plugins.